# php - Implicit conversion from float 2.3283064365386963E-10 to int loses precision

Tags: php

I am using php 8.2 on windows on the following code:

```
    private static function urs($a, $b) {   
        $a &= 0xffffffff;
        $b &= 0x1f;
        if ($a&0x80000000 && $b>0){
            $a = ($a>>1) & 0x7fffffff;
            $a = $a >> ($b-1);
        } else {
            $a = ($a>>$b);
        }
        return $a; 
    }


$a &= 0xffffffff; <- this line giving error
```

> Implicit conversion from float 2.3283064365386963E-10 to int loses precision

earlier on 5.4 the same function doesn't given any error

Comment: @shingo no this does give my answer

Comment: It's quite easy to [look up what the problem is](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=php+deprecated+implicit+conversion+from+float+to+int+loses+precision), but solving it can be difficult. You make it harder for us to help you because you didn't tell us what this static method is supposed to accomplish, nor did you given us some sensible input and out output values so we can test any changes we make. Can you add these to your question?

Comment: But your thread doesn't contain a question.

Comment: This appears to be a deprecation notice rather than an actual error. It just means it'll cause an error in some future php version, but for now it's still allowed

Comment: I think closing this question as a duplicate is premature. An answer requires an explanation as to why `0xffffffff;` is seen as a float.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Wait a second, I thought this message meant that `$a` is a float, but you seem to have discovered a new problem.

Comment: @shingo Yes, the weird thing here is that you get the warning even if you use an integer for `$a`, but this seems to solve it: `$a = $a & (int)0xffffffff;`. I am not certain this will always perform the same as `$a = $a & 0xffffffff;`?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Interesting, I guess you tested on 3v4l, the live preview gave me PHP_INT_MAX = 2147483647, but if I hit the eval(); button, the result became 9223372036854775807. Given that the OP only mentioned one line warning, I should assume that he is using 64-bit PHP.